# Firebase transaction count Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node that lists my games waiting for an opponent. For example I can have in this node :

gamestomatch
    - KgUjq9SBp84Pca4ozD8: history
    - KgUmOIAlVyc4M4wMMc6: geography
    - KgW0qGT3lRi22X-V7p3: sport
    - KgWhrWWhYlIKm5XbGzy: sport
    - KgWhu3BZktRHD65zoAQ: history

It's a turn-based 2-player quiz game, so when a player starts a new game it checks if someone else already started a game in the list above. If there is a match I delete the game from the list, if not I start a new game and add it to the list.

I use a transaction to avoid several players picking the same game in the list. My issue is that I don't want doTransaction() to be called 25 times and I want to avoid the case where all the doTransaction() calls are rejected. Is it ok to count the doTransaction() calls as below, and use this count to create a new game if first and second transactions have been rejected ?

mynode.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            int transactionRun = 0;

```
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            if (transactionRun <= 1) {
                //look for an existing game in the list, if none exists then create a new one
                transactionRun++;

                if (transactionRun > 1) {
                    // create a new game
                }
            }
```

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time on SO.  Also I don't know what you're trying to achieve by limiting your transaction loop.  You should expect that it can get called more than once.  That's OK.  It's how the database makes sure all pending writes can be ordered and executed properly.  I think you're unnecessarily worrying.

Comment: Understood, I have edited my posty to keep one question only :) I want to limit the number of transaction loops because it takes time to call 25 times the update function of the transaction, I guess it won"t happen often but I don't want players to have to wait dozens of seconds to find an existing game. I find it already long enough with one call. So after one or a few calls I want to create a new game instead of trying to find an existing one. Do you know if my code is correct to count the update function calls and to adapt the behaviour of the app according to this count ?

Comment: How are you observing that your transaction actually gets invoked 25 times?  A transaction is only executed more than twice when there is actual write contention for that node in the database.  I'm still thinking you're worried over something that in practice would not actually happen often, if at all.